# Create directories anywhere in windows 7?

Tags: c++, windows, directory, creation

I have an application that requires that a DLL be able to create various directories in it's current location.  However, from looking around, I have found that windows 7 apparently restricts the ability of programs to write in a lot of places.  I cannot redesign the application, as the DLL is injected into a process and creates log files that the user would view.  I don't want to shove them in appdata, is there any other way to do what I want?

Comment: For security reasons, you must not do that.

Comment: If dll should save smth for user, why don't save in _documents_?

Comment: What is "its current location" ? Current Working Directory? Directory that holds the DLL? The hosting EXE?

Answer (score 0):

You can try to change the current working directory with SetCurrentDirectory

Comment: This would allow me to create folders?

Comment: If you dll makes directories in the current working directory (which is usually the folder where the executable is) it can make folders in it. But your application must choose a new working directory where you have rights to write in. (in the Documents folder for example)

Comment: Executables are usually in `C:\Program Files\`, and users are usually unable to write there. So, not going to work there. Generally, the "Current Working Directory" is just a shortcut so you can write `.\something` instead of `c:\long\path\to\something`. Using the shortcut does not give you any special rights, which would be needed for this question.